# Batch enroll multiple educationUsers to educationClass

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

In the beta (and v1.0) endpoints of the Microsoft graph, for "education", is there a way to add multiple teachers and members (educationUser references) to an "educationClass"?

```
POST /education/classes/{id}/members/$ref

{
  "@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/users/XXXXX"
}
```

Right now, it seems that one by one is added instead of batch applying this in the same fashion as when adding members and owners to teams.

Something like this? (fictive request)

```
"teachers@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/users/AAAAA",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/users/BBBBB"
],
"members@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/users/CCCCC",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/education/users/DDDDD"
]
```

Either in a separate $ref operation or directly on the educationClass creation request object.

Is this something I've just been missing when looking in the doc? If not, is this something the Microsoft Graph Education team might consider in a future version of the beta endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the `group` resource (and by extension `educationClass`) only supports adding one Owner/Member at a time. You may want to look into the [JSON Batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) functionality. Batching allows you to queue up to 20 Graph calls in a single request.

For managing Teacher, Student, and Class assignment at scale, I'd suggest looking at [School Data Sync](https://sds.microsoft.com/) (SDS). SDS allows you to automatically keep your AAD in sync with a Student Information System.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking at the batching before and in that particular problem, batching didn't apply that well. But this might be a better scenario. SDS is out of scope in this scenario as it doesn't apply to the current problem (I am well aware of SDS, pros and cons). This should be possible to do via the Graph API, so I'm keeping this one open in case this is something that could be put into the pipeline at Microsoft at some point.

Comment: I'll actually accept this as an answer, for the Batching part. I see that more and more endpoints are doing it this was. Annoying, but probably a reason for it. Thanks 